# Can I load Clonezilla not from USB but from my main internal HDD?

Tags: backup, clonezilla

I use Clonezilla for backups. For that I write image to USB, loading from it and make image to my second PC.

Can I load Clonezilla not from USB but from HDD of my laptop?

Answer (score 0):

Unclear what you are asking, but here goes my guess.

I assume you are asking if it is possible to run clonezilla without booting from a usb first.

You can run clonezilla, but you can not clone any mounted disks. In other words, you can not clone the disk from which clonezilla is running. You can clone other disks, if you have any.

Comment: But Clonezilla can load itself to RAM and unmount disk - isn't it?

Comment: That I am not aware of. but it definitely can not clone a mounted disk.